# How to get collision detection of circle and triangle

Tags: c++, collision-detection

I have one triangle ad one circle moving objects on plane.How will i know both of them are collide to each other. ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Circle - triangle interesction test is what you want 
http://www.phatcode.net/articles.php?id=459