# 2D planet terrain collisions with sphere

Tags: 2d, physics, terrain

I'm making a game with a similar concept to Super Mario Galaxy, but two dimensional. If you're unfamiliar with the gravity in SMG, you can watch [this quick video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FFoZeD7S4EU)

My game world is made up of an array of data. 0 is the equivalent of 'nothing' or 'space', and 1+ are the different types of terrain. I'm already able to calculate the center of gravity, and the strength of the gravity on an object depending on it's distance from the planet etc...

My problem is with collision detection.

[image: Photo 1]

I'm successfully applying gravity to the circle in the form of momentum (`xspeed`/`yspeed`), but I'm not sure how to determine if the circle is colliding with a 'cube' and how to prevent the circle from overlapping any of the cubes.

[image: Photo 2]

Each cell of the world is a certain width (something like `10` pixels; it's in a static variable). The player (circle) will have a sprite, but it will be treated as a circle for collisions and such, so nothing advanced (like torque) is needed. Obviously the circle will need to move perpendicular to the gravity (and slide across the planet).

[image]

So basically I'm asking for pseudocode, or just a concept. I really don't think an entire physics library is at all necessary, this seems like it should be doable with a fairly simple technique.

**EDIT:** Also, it won't just be standing/walking on the surface. There will be obstacles that are too high to walk over. In this picture, for example, the player would probably be trapped:

[image]

Comment: You just need to represent the boundary of your terrain using line segments, and check that the circle does not cross any one segment.  It's pretty basic to test whether a line and two points are inside/outside or intersecting a circle.

Comment: I would do it in steps, the first one would be create bounding circles to the objects and check if the bounding circles colide. If yes, do a more refined search.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16440398/javascript-collision-detection-between-circle-and-polygon) maybe will help.

Comment: @Joqus Or just use a quad-tree...

Comment: @paddy Yeah, also an option