# How can I check if a circle is intersecting a triangle in a 2 dimensional space?

Tags: geometry, processing

This is needed for a program I am working now. The only information I have to work with is the coordinates of the vertices of a triangle, the coordinates of the center of the circle and the diameter of the circle. How would I figure out if a circle is touching/intersecting a triangle in a 2 dimensional space? I am using Processing.

Comment: Could you show own attempts?

Comment: @MBo I can't figure out how to do it. I'm still in the brainstorming stage, and haven't put any ideas to test.

Answer (score 1):

Stack Overflow isn't really designed for general "how do I do this" type questions. It's for specific "I tried X, expected Y, but got Z instead" type questions. But I'll try to help in a general sense:

The best thing you can do is Google stuff like [circle triangle intersection](https://www.google.com/search?q=circle+triangle+intersection) or [circle triangle collision detection](https://www.google.com/search?q=circle+triangle+collision+detection). You'll find a ton of results, including:

- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/867627/intersection-of-a-circle-and-a-triangle
- [How to get collision detection of circle and triangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5518940/how-to-get-collision-detection-of-circle-and-triangle)
- https://www.gamedev.net/forums/topic/406403-circle-in-triangle-intersection/

The point is, you shouldn't be afraid to do some research. Try to put together a small example program (aka a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) and ask a more specific question if you get stuck. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1. Check squared distances from circle center (CC) to every vertex of triangle

if they are too large:

2. Check whether CC is inside triangle (using signs of cross-products)

if not:

3. Calculate projections of CC onto triangle edges (line segments) using scalar products. If projection is inside edge, calculate distance from CC to edge.

Comment: I think I could do it if I checked if it was crossing any of the edges. It would be simpler. I just need to check if the X crosses some bit, while the Y is at a specific range.

Comment: Also could you rephrase this simply?

Comment: Edge crossing is the most time-consuming calculation here, so at first check simpler cases in order I gave.